# CSS Animations won't play inside iframe on IE11

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I am currently writing a HTML5/JS Webapp which will be integrated into pre-existing HTML code. The pre-existing code contains an `iframe` which then loads the URL of my webapp.

I have the following animation set up in my CSS file:

```
@-moz-keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

.container .left .people-container .people .person.slideInLeft {
  -webkit-animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
  -moz-animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
  animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
}
```

Now if I start my webapp in a window of its own, then the animation plays without issue, however when the webapp is loaded through the iframe, the animation does not fire (Note: This issue only occurs in IE11. Chrome, Firefox and Edge all work correctly both in iframe and out).

The `slideInLeft` class is definitely attached to the HTML Elements I want to animate, and the `@keyframes` are definitely in the loaded CSS, but the animation will still not play.

Following images are directly from the IE11 Dev Console:

[image: Class is attached to the div]
[image: Keyframes show up in the CSS]

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have since found out what the issue was. The parent page which contained the iframe that loaded my webapp had the following `meta` tag in the `head` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Modifying this to be

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10">
```

Which allowed the animations to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add non-prefix at the end

```
 @-moz-keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
      0% {
        left: -500px;
      }
      100% {
        left: 0px;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
      0% {
        left: -500px;
      }
      100% {
        left: 0px;
      }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
      0% {
        left: -500px;
      }
      100% {
        left: 0px;
      }
    }
    @keyframes peopleSlideLeft {
      0% {
        left: -500px;
      }
      100% {
        left: 0px;
      }
    }

    .container .left .people-container .people .person.slideInLeft {
      -webkit-animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
      -moz-animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
      -ms-animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
      animation: peopleSlideLeft 0.75s forwards;
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `@keyframes` and `animation` properties without any prefixes? Because I already have those as you can see from my question.

Comment: yes, I mean without prefixes. and if you have seen in my answer I have added the animation for -ms-animation.

Comment: The `-ms-` prefix has not been needed for animations since the [IE10 Developer Previews](https://www.impressivewebs.com/dropping-ms-vendor-prefixes-ie10/), however I added it anyway and it did not fix the issue.